# VBA .AddPicture with late binding Error 424

Tags: vba, excel, visio

Using the below code i get a 424 error "Object Required" on the .AddPicure line as indicated.  I'm unsure as to why as pic is dimensioned as object, and the .addpicture comand looks fully referenced to me.

Apologies for the length of code, i thought it best to leave in all variables.

I'm using Excel 13 from MS Visio 16, and late binding is necessary.

**Edit:  Sorry, it is infact an add text box line thats giving me the problem, I've updated the code below...

```
Sub testexcel()

Dim pic As Object
Dim rng As Object
Dim tWidth As Long, tHeight As Long

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWb = xlApp.workbooks.Open("C:\Users\tom\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")
Set xlWs = xlWb.sheets("Sheet1")

xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False
Set rng = xlWs.Range("B18")
Set rng2 = xlWs.Range("A1", rng.Offset(-1, -1))

picture1 = "C:\Users\tom\Desktop\PX001.bmp"

pHeight = 145
pWidth = 200
tHeight = 10
tWidth = 200
posX = 10
posY = 10


'On Error GoTo ErrMsg
With xlWs.Range("A1", rng.Offset(-1, -1))
'*******Problem on next line*******
    Set txtBx = xlWs.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 
txtPosX, txtPosY, tWidth, tHeight).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "FooBar"
End With
'Some other code here...
End Sub
```

Comment: Strangely when i move the text frame out of the with clause it works fine as below.

    txtBx.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "FooBar"

Comment: It's not because you moved it outside of the `With` scope but because you split it up. See my answer for details. Did you remove code from the `With` scope? Because you don't use it at all in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try splitting it up

```
Set txtBx = xlWs.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, txtPosX, txtPosY, tWidth, tHeight)
txtBx.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "FooBar"
```

I think this is what's happening:

```
xlWs.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, txtPosX, txtPosY, tWidth, tHeight).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "FooBar"
```

This retunrs false because the second `=` is interpreted as a comparison. Then you are basically doing `Set txtBx = False` which causes the error.

It could also be that vba tries to assign the `Text` property which is a string to `txtBx`.

edit: I would also suggest using `Option Explicit`. If VBA knows that `txtBx` is supposed to be a shape, it tells you it got a type mismatch. In this case you got lucky because the `Set` tells it to expect an object and thus threw an error. If you wanted to assign a string for example, you would have gotten the error at a later line (or no error at all) because you have `False` where you expect a string which makes debugging more complicated.